# Initialize Properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So I have a class where I need to initialize some properties *once* after the first initialization. These properties need to not be reinitialized the whole run of the program. How do I do this in iOS 7 SDK? I tried use `initWithNibName`, but it doesn't run, at all. Same with `init`. What method should I use?

Here's my code

```
PSACurrentGame.h:


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "phase10Scorer.h"

@interface PSACurrentGame : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *playerNamesArray;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL moveNums;
@property (strong, nonatomic) phase10Scorer *scorer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *R1Scores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *R1Phases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *R2Scores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *R2Phases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *R3Scores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *R3Phases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ToScores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ToPhases;

@end
```

PSACurrentGame.m:

```
#import "PSACurrentGame.h"
#import "phase10Scorer.h"

@interface PSACurrentGame ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *round1Scores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *round1Phases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *round2Scores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *round2Phases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *round3Scores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *round3Phases;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *totalScores;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *totalPhases;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *playerNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *roundLabelsSecondSet;


@end

@implementation PSACurrentGame

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.scorer = [[phase10Scorer alloc] init];
        self.R1Scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
         self.R1Phases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.R2Scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.R2Phases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.R3Scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.R3Phases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.ToScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.ToPhases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        self.moveNums = true;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    int j = 0;
    for (UILabel *playerLabel in self.playerNames) {
        playerLabel.text = self.playerNamesArray[j];
        j++;
    }

    if (self.moveNums) {


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.R3Scores[i] = self.R2Scores[i];
        self.R2Scores[i] = self.R1Scores[i];
        self.R1Scores[i] = self.ToScores[i];

        self.R3Phases[i] = self.R2Phases[i];
        self.R2Phases[i] = self.R1Phases[i];
        self.R1Phases[i] = self.ToPhases[i];

        self.ToScores[i] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([self.scorer getScores:(i + 1)])];
        self.ToPhases[i] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([self.scorer getPhases:(i + 1)])];
    }
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (UILabel *tf in self.totalScores) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            pName.hidden = true;
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.ToScores[i];
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.totalPhases) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.ToPhases[i];
        i++;
    }

        i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.round1Scores) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.R1Scores[i];
        i++;
    }

        i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.round1Phases) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.R1Phases[i];
        i++;
    }

        i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.round2Scores) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.R2Scores[i];
        i++;
    }

        i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.round2Phases) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.R2Phases[i];
        i++;
    }

        i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.round3Scores) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.R1Scores[i];
        i++;
    }

        i = 0;

    for (UILabel *tf in self.round3Phases) {
        UILabel *pName = self.playerNames[i];
        if ([pName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            tf.hidden = true;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        tf.text = self.R1Phases[i];
        i++;
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: If I get your question you want to initialize it just once, then use a singleton class.

Comment: Not related to your question : To have a more readable code you can use new literals format for numbers (@0 instead of [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use awakeFromNib instead.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
     //Custom initialization
}
```

initWithNibName is not called when you instantiate a view controller from a XIB or storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are also `initWithStyle:` and `initWithCoder:` :)

You could modify them all but I think an easier solution would be to use a 'lazy initialization'.
For instance, in your interface you have a `@property` defined like so:

```
@interface YourClass
...
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) YourType* propertyName;
...
@end
```

Note the `readonly` attribute. This means, that there will be no publicly accessible setter for this property (you mentioned, that these properties won't ever be modified).
Then in your `.m` file you can define a category:

```
@interface YourClass()
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) YourType* propertyName; //this will give us a private setter.
...
@end
```

And then you define a getter like so:

```
@implementation
...
-(YourType*)propertyName
{
    if (nil == _propertyName)
    {
        //initialize _propertyName here. This code will run once.
    }
    return _propertyName;
}
...
@end
```

This way properties will be initialized on demand. The good thing is that there is a guarantee that they'll be initialized. The bad thing is that the first call to these methods would take more time. But there is another plus: object creation is cheaper.

P.S. This code uses ARC.

Comment: I never said I would never modify these properties. They are modified frequently. I just only want to _initialize_ them once.

Comment: @DonyorM, oh, sorry. I misunderstood you then.